# Ruby on Rails Button Link to controller doesn't appear

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, controller, action, link-to

This is weird! I have an html.erb form, and in this form I have a button that links the user to an action in another controller (finance_extensions) to print pdf. This is working great, but the thing is that I need my own action that I'm using in the current controller (parent_wise_fee_payments), so I added this same action + view file to my controller and I changed this in pay_all_fees.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "► #{t('print_receipt')}",

                  {:controller => "finance_extensions", :action => "pay_all_fees_receipt_pdf", :id => student.id}, :target => '_blank', :class => 'user_button' %>
```

to this:

```
  <%= link_to "► #{t('print_receipt')}",

                      {:controller => "parent_wise_fee_payments", :action => "pay_all_fees_receipt_pdf", :id => student.id}, :target => '_blank', :class => 'user_button' %>
```

This causes the button to disapper. I also tried adding a test action and view in my controller, and tried removing " :controller" but it didn't solve my problem.

Is this weird or am I missing something here?!

Comment: Does the HTML for the button show up when you do a "view source" from your browser? Did anything else at all change in the code in areas that might be related to this change in line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add your new action to the auth file in the config??

Comment: Omg I forgot!! It's working now, thank you soooooooo much!!